# Polymorphism is the only solution

Tags: polymorphism

Title says it all.

I need a scenario where polymorphism is the only solution. I have seen many threads with benefits of polymorphism but I think, scenario where solution with only polymorphism is missing.

Another way of asking same question is:

> "What is the origin of polymorphism?"

Comment: "I need a scenario" - I believe that the purpose of this exercise is to make *you* think - not us :)  First, can you find alternatives to polymorphism ? Second, can you come up with *any* scenario/s to polymorphism ? start by answering these questions and then start looking for a good use-case. Good luck!

Comment: _First, can you find alternatives to polymorphism ?_ 
Redundant code will be the result as an alternative. 

_Second, can you come up with any scenario/s to polymorphism ?_ 
You want me to answer this or you want me to think only? :)
Multiple scenarios.

Comment: Redundant code is not the only alternative. You can use *composition* as well. If you can come up with multiple scenarios, doesn't any of them justifies using polymorphism ?

Comment: Redundant code or composition are the alternatives. So I think we are going in wrong direction. Question was "polymorphism is the only solution"

Comment: Redundant code or composition are alternatives to polymorphism. This is a general statement. You are looking for a case where these are *bad* alternatives because of a quality that polymorphism has that the alternatives lack.

Comment: I am not looking for a _bad_ alternative. I am looking for a case where there is _no_ alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somehow open to interpretation.

Let me try to answer your question by first draw a line between:

1. Polymorphism as an abstract concept
2. Polymorphism directly supported by programming languages and compilers like C++, Java, C#, etc

The default example for polymorphism might be a vector graphics tool like e.g. Corel Draw, Inkscape.
Assume you would like the user to be able draw several different geographical shapes (square, triangle, circle) on a canvas.

I now suggest that the CONCEPT of polymorphism is the only solution to that problem while at the same time of course you will be very well able to write a solution in any programming language, including those not offering an integral polymorphism mechanism (like e.g. C).

The explicit polymorphism will become evident in form of several 'if' conditions.

So:
The CONCEPT of Polymorphism is always the only solution, if:

1. you have several c l a s s e s of entities which share a subset of common behavior, but also each class having some special behavior special for that class only
2. at compile you do not know what concrete class will be required, only at runtime

Your add on question about the 'origin' of Polymorphism.
The concept of polymorphism is something eminent, like Primes, at least I feel this way.
The implicit support of Polymorphism in programming languages has started with C++ in the early 90s, early WYSWG programs like Corel Draw and Word and 
[THE book](https://www.google.de/search?q=design%20patterns%20gamma) 
(that is of course a personal observation)

Below an example.

```
// example WITH implicit polymorphism
abstract class PolyGeometricEntity
{
    public int center_x__mm;                    // commen superset
    public int center_y__mm;                    // commen superset
    public void move(int d_x__mm, int d_y_mm)   // commen superset
    {
        center_x__mm += d_x__mm;
        center_y__mm += d_y_mm:
    }

    public abstract int area();                 // commen superset on abstract level, but specialized at implementation level
    public abstract void draw();               // commen superset on abstract level, but specialized at implementation level
}

class CircleEntity : PolyGeometricEntity
{
    public override int area()
    {
        // circle specific
        return 1;
    }
    public override void draw()
    {
        // draw a circle
    }
}

class TriangleEntity : PolyGeometricEntity
{
    public override int area()
    {
        // triangle specific
        return 1;
    }
    public override void draw()
    {
        // draw a triangle
    }
}


class PolyCanvas
{
    List<PolyGeometricEntity> entities = new List<PolyGeometricEntity>();

    void CreateEntity(string toCreateClass)
    {
        // assume that code is called by the ui
        // you do not know what the user decides at runtime
        // Polymorphism 'starting' now:
        PolyGeometricEntity toCreate = null;
        if (toCreateClass == "c") { toCreate = new CircleEntity(); }
        else if (toCreateClass == "t") { toCreate = new TriangleEntity(); }
        entities.Add(toCreate);
    }

    void ReDraw()
    {
        foreach (PolyGeometricEntity toDraw in entities)
        {
            toDraw.draw(); // polymorphism in action!
        }
    }
}


// example WITHOUT implicit polymorphism
abstract class NonPolyGeometricEntity
{
    public int center_x__mm;                    // commen superset
    public int center_y__mm;                    // commen superset

    public string entityClass;                  

    public void move(int d_x__mm, int d_y_mm)   // commen superset
    {

    }

    // explicid Polymorphism, but concept of Polymorphism still present 
    public int area()
    {
        if (entityClass == "c")
        {
            // return area of cirlce
        }
        else if (entityClass == "t")
        {
            // return area of triangle
        }
        return 0;
    }
    public void draw()
    {
        if (entityClass == "c")
        {
            // draw area of cirlce
        }
        else if (entityClass == "t")
        {
            // draw area of triangle
        }
    }
}





class NonPolyCanvas
{
    List<NonPolyGeometricEntity> entities = new List<NonPolyGeometricEntity>();

    void CreateEntity(string toCreateClass)
    {
        // assume that code is called by the ui
        // you do not know what the user decides at runtime
        NonPolyGeometricEntity toCreate = null;
        toCreate.entityClass = toCreateClass;   //explit polymorphism
        entities.Add(toCreate);
    }

    void ReDraw()
    {
        foreach (NonPolyGeometricEntity toDraw in entities)
        {
            toDraw.draw(); 
        }
    }
}
```